# MyBatis could not get record when using selectByPrimaryKey ocassionally

Tags: java, mybatis

Today I found the same http request to the backend api server, sometimes it could fetch the article, sometimes it could not fetch the article, this is my code:

```
Article article = articleMapper.selectByPrimaryKey(id);
```

and this is the code generate automaticlly using MyBatis Generator:

```
 <select id="selectByPrimaryKey" parameterType="java.lang.Long" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbggenerated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
    -->
    select 
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from article
    where id = #{id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
  </select>
```

the same http request, with the same article id. I do not know where is going wrong.My PostgreSQL version is 13. And this is my auto generate xml config:

```
 <table tableName="article"
            enableCountByExample="true"
            enableUpdateByExample="true"
            enableDeleteByExample="true"
            enableSelectByExample="true"
            selectByExampleQueryId="true">
            <generatedKey column="ID" sqlStatement="JDBC" identity="true" />
        </table>
```

any clue to figure out what wrong with the code? I am a newbie about PostgreSQL as backend database.

- Does the article with the id you're querying for exist? Yes, I am sure the ID exists.
- Could there be concurrent modifications? No, It is impossible. I will never edit the article after write into database. No transactions,The article is an old article.

Comment: Does the article with the id you're querying for exist? Could there be concurrent modifications, e.g. the article being created or deleted in "parallel" transactions so that isolation hits you? - "Occasionally" isn't an easy thing to debug or solve, especially given the limited amount of information you can provide here. You should try to gather more information so maybe a pattern emerges that let's you reproduce the behavior. Information how to reproduce it or at least info like "it mostly happens when xyz happens as well" would help to narrow down the cause for this.

Comment: This problem makes me so confused. I will try to reproduce it.@Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I observe this after I use `selectByPrimaryKey(null)` to query record.  I add a check before `selectByPrimaryKey` to ensure that it cannot get a null parameter. And other `selectByPrimary(id)` is OK.

Comment: Please use answering posts only to answer. If you cannot answer according to [answer] please wait for your commenting privilege. I [edit]ed for you, to reduce this to what I think may be accepted as an answer. Please review and in case you do not see this as an answer you can give and cannot edit it yourself into one, then please delete this post. Otherwise welcome to StackOverflow.